# How to match the YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD timezone format in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to check the iso8601 format for the date entered in ruby , like **start_date = "2011/05/05"** should be matched for the format **2011-05-05T00:00:00-04:00**  and errors returned accordingly. 
Should we use regex here or any method is present for this?

Comment: clarifications ...If i provide text = "2011-02-30T00:00:00" parsed = Time.iso8601(text) gives => Wed Mar 02 00:00:00 +0000 2011 , adjusting the date , can we avoid this and throw errors.Shall i go for custom validation or it's available., also Time.iso8601(text) crashes the application when invalid date is provided, can we just return boolean after matching...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Time.iso8601`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-iso8601):

```
require 'time'
iso = Time.iso8601(start_date)
```

See [this blog post](http://avdi.org/devblog/2009/10/25/iso8601-dates-in-ruby/) for more information.

EDIT: Here's a short but complete test program which works:

```
require 'time'
text = "2011-05-05T00:00:00-04:00"
parsed = Time.iso8601(text)
puts parsed
```

Output:

```
Thu May 05 04:00:00 UTC 2011
```

Comment: `Time.iso8601` does not take a string as argument (should be a date or time object).

Comment: @jon thanx!.. just a clarification . If i provide text = "2011-02-30T00:00:00"  parsed = Time.iso8601(text) gives 
 => Wed Mar 02 00:00:00 +0000 2011 , adjusting the date , can we avoid this and throw errors.Shall i go for custom validation or it's available.

Comment: @GhostRider: No idea, I'm afraid. I'm not a Ruby dev - just thought I'd have a punt at this one...

Answer (score 4):

For regex validation ( with optional microseconds and time zone) use :

```
^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?$
```

Test on:
http://rubular.com/r/qFFrhzvdsS

**Not recommended in scripts when performance matters**!